# What methods can we use to reshape VERY large data sets?

Tags: r, performance, bigdata, reshape

When due to very large data calculations will take a long time and, hence, we don't want them to crash, it would be valuable to know beforehand which reshape method to use.

Lately, methods for reshaping data have been further developed regarding performance, e.g. `data.table::dcast` and `tidyr::spread`. Especially `dcast.data.table` seems to set the tone <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20387444/6574038), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22375961/6574038), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35000588/6574038),
[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36253517/6574038)</sup>. This makes other methods as base R's `reshape` in benchmarks seem outdated and almost useless <sup>[[5]](http://www.kimberlycoffey.com/blog/2016/9/updated-big-data-wrangling)</sup>.

### Theory

***However***, I've heard that `reshape` was still unbeatable when it comes to very large datasets (probably those exceeding RAM)  because it's the only method that can handle them and therefore it still has it's right to exist. A related crash report using `reshape2::dcast` supports this point <sup>[[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28986836/6574038)</sup>. At least one reference gives a hint that `reshape()` might indeed had advantages over `reshape2::dcast` for really "big stuff" <sup>[[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495680/6574038)</sup>.

### Method

Seeking evidence for that, I thought it was worth the time to do some research. So I did a benchmark with simulated data of different size which increasingly exhaust the RAM to compare `reshape`, `dcast`, `dcast.data.table`, and `spread`. I looked at simple datasets with three columns, with the various number of rows to obtain different sizes (see the code at the very bottom).

```
> head(df1, 3)
  id                 tms         y
1  1 1970-01-01 01:00:01 0.7463622
2  2 1970-01-01 01:00:01 0.1417795
3  3 1970-01-01 01:00:01 0.6993089
```

The RAM size was just 8 GB, which was my threshold to simulate "very large" datasets. In order to keep the time for the calculations reasonable, I made only 3 measurements for each method and focused on reshaping from long to wide.

## Results

```
unit: seconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval size.gb size.ram
1  dcast.DT        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA     3    8.00    1.000
2     dcast        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA     3    8.00    1.000
3     tidyr        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA     3    8.00    1.000
4   reshape 490988.37 492843.94 494699.51 495153.48 497236.03 499772.56     3    8.00    1.000
5  dcast.DT   3288.04   4445.77   5279.91   5466.31   6375.63  10485.21     3    4.00    0.500
6     dcast   5151.06   5888.20   6625.35   6237.78   6781.14   6936.93     3    4.00    0.500
7     tidyr   5757.26   6398.54   7039.83   6653.28   7101.28   7162.74     3    4.00    0.500
8   reshape  85982.58  87583.60  89184.62  88817.98  90235.68  91286.74     3    4.00    0.500
9  dcast.DT      2.18      2.18      2.18      2.18      2.18      2.18     3    0.20    0.025
10    tidyr      3.19      3.24      3.37      3.29      3.46      3.63     3    0.20    0.025
11    dcast      3.46      3.49      3.57      3.52      3.63      3.74     3    0.20    0.025
12  reshape    277.01    277.53    277.83    278.05    278.24    278.42     3    0.20    0.025
13 dcast.DT      0.18      0.18      0.18      0.18      0.18      0.18     3    0.02    0.002
14    dcast      0.34      0.34      0.35      0.34      0.36      0.37     3    0.02    0.002
15    tidyr      0.37      0.39      0.42      0.41      0.44      0.48     3    0.02    0.002
16  reshape     29.22     29.37     29.49     29.53     29.63     29.74     3    0.02    0.002
```

[image]

<sup>(*Note:* Benchmarks were performed on a secondary MacBook Pro with Intel Core i5 2.5 GHz, 8GB DDR3 RAM 1600 MHz.)</sup>

Obviously, `dcast.data.table` seems to be always the fastest. As expected, all packaged approaches failed with very large data sets, probably because the calculations then exceeded the RAM memory:

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Timing stopped at: 1.597e+04 1.864e+04 5.254e+04
```

Only `reshape` handled all data sizes, albeit very slowly.

### Conclusion

Package methods like `dcast` and `spread` are invaluable for data sets that are smaller than the RAM or whose calculations do not exhaust the RAM. If the data set is larger than the RAM memory, package methods will fail and we should use `reshape`.

### Question

Could we conclude like this? Could someone clarify a little why the `data.table/reshape` and `tidyr` methods fail and what their methodological differences are to `reshape`? Is the only alternative for vast data the reliable but slow horse `reshape`? What can we expect from methods that have not been tested here as `tapply`, `unstack`, and `xtabs` approaches <sup>[[8]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/6574038),
[[9]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9617348/6574038)</sup>?

***Or, in short:*** What faster alternative is there if anything but `reshape` fails?

---

### Data/Code

```
# 8GB version
n <- 1e3      
t1 <- 2.15e5  # approx. 8GB, vary to increasingly exceed RAM

df1 <- expand.grid(id=1:n, tms=as.POSIXct(1:t1, origin="1970-01-01"))
df1$y <- rnorm(nrow(df1))

dim(df1)
# [1] 450000000         3

> head(df1, 3)
id                 tms         y
1  1 1970-01-01 01:00:01 0.7463622
2  2 1970-01-01 01:00:01 0.1417795
3  3 1970-01-01 01:00:01 0.6993089

object.size(df1)
# 9039666760 bytes

library(data.table)
DT1 <- as.data.table(df1)

library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyr)
# NOTE: this runs for quite a while!
mbk <- microbenchmark(reshape=reshape(df1, idvar="tms", timevar="id", direction="wide"),
                      dcast=dcast(df1, tms ~ id, value.var="y"),
                      dcast.dt=dcast(DT1, tms ~ id, value.var="y"),
                      tidyr=spread(df1, id, y),
                      times=3L)
```

Comment: My loose definition of "big data" revolves around *"problems larger than the RAM on your computer"*, suggesting it is a moving target and dependent on the computer being used (big data on my 256GB ram server is different than my 16GB ram laptop). With that in mind, it sounds like you are experimenting with methods that are either near this limit or exceeding it, in which case I suggest your methodology should involve cluster-based approaches. Lacking a nearby cluster, this can be simulated in R with divide-and-conquer, meaning `split`, then reshape, then `rbind` (one of the variants).

Comment: Long-story-short, I don't know the answer to your specific question of `reshape` efficiencies. But if your efforts really are to find a way to deal with data on your local system, then I suggest split-apply-combine is a viable alternative for larger datasets.

Comment: How did you get size in the output from `microbenchmark`?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your hints. I combined the data frames of the four measurements with different data size, obtained with `summary(<microbenchmark>)`, and added this columns manually.

Comment: Bummer, I was *really* hoping to have that simple profiling in `microbenchmark`, it would have been quite informative. For the record, `rbindlist(by(DT1, DT1$tms, function(x) dcast(x, tms ~ id, value.var = "y")))` produced the same output (once sorted) as `dcast(DT1, tms ~ id, value.var="y")`, albeit taking *significantly* longer to calculate. I suspect it uses less memory overall, though I cannot verify at the moment.

Comment: This is an interesting question, that could use more attention. If no reliable implementation exists reshaping large data sets (although i doubt it), one could use [feather datasets](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/) to quickly divide the dataset in seperate data frames (files really), to then reshape individually and finally combine. Although this would be somewhat of a workaround, it might still be faster than using the `stats` implementation `reshape`, as the feather files seems fast for temporary storage.

Comment: @jay.sf would you entertain using using python/r through `reticulate`  as a possible solution?

Answer (score 13):

If your real data is as regular as your sample data we can be quite efficient by noticing that reshaping a matrix is really just changing its dim attribute.

**1st on very small data**

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyr)

matrix_spread <- function(df1, key, value){
  unique_ids <-  unique(df1[[key]])
  mat <- matrix( df1[[value]], ncol= length(unique_ids),byrow = TRUE)
  df2 <- data.frame(unique(df1["tms"]),mat)
  names(df2)[-1] <- paste0(value,".",unique_ids)
  df2
}

n <- 3      
t1 <- 4
df1 <- expand.grid(id=1:n, tms=as.POSIXct(1:t1, origin="1970-01-01"))
df1$y <- rnorm(nrow(df1))

reshape(df1, idvar="tms", timevar="id", direction="wide")
#                    tms        y.1        y.2       y.3
# 1  1970-01-01 01:00:01  0.3518667  0.6350398 0.1624978
# 4  1970-01-01 01:00:02  0.3404974 -1.1023521 0.5699476
# 7  1970-01-01 01:00:03 -0.4142585  0.8194931 1.3857788
# 10 1970-01-01 01:00:04  0.3651138 -0.9867506 1.0920621

matrix_spread(df1, "id", "y")
#                    tms        y.1        y.2       y.3
# 1  1970-01-01 01:00:01  0.3518667  0.6350398 0.1624978
# 4  1970-01-01 01:00:02  0.3404974 -1.1023521 0.5699476
# 7  1970-01-01 01:00:03 -0.4142585  0.8194931 1.3857788
# 10 1970-01-01 01:00:04  0.3651138 -0.9867506 1.0920621

all.equal(check.attributes = FALSE,
          reshape(df1, idvar="tms", timevar="id", direction="wide"),
          matrix_spread (df1, "id", "y"))
# TRUE
```

**Then on bigger data**

(sorry I can't afford to make a huge computation now)

```
n <- 100      
t1 <- 5000

df1 <- expand.grid(id=1:n, tms=as.POSIXct(1:t1, origin="1970-01-01"))
df1$y <- rnorm(nrow(df1))

DT1 <- as.data.table(df1)

microbenchmark(reshape=reshape(df1, idvar="tms", timevar="id", direction="wide"),
               dcast=dcast(df1, tms ~ id, value.var="y"),
               dcast.dt=dcast(DT1, tms ~ id, value.var="y"),
               tidyr=spread(df1, id, y),
               matrix_spread = matrix_spread(df1, "id", "y"),
               times=3L)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr                 min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
# reshape       4197.08012 4240.59316 4260.58806 4284.10620 4292.34203 4300.57786     3
# dcast           57.31247   78.16116   86.93874   99.00986  101.75189  104.49391     3
# dcast.dt       114.66574  120.19246  127.51567  125.71919  133.94064  142.16209     3
# tidyr           55.12626   63.91142   72.52421   72.69658   81.22319   89.74980     3
# matrix_spread   15.00522   15.42655   17.45283   15.84788   18.67664   21.50539     3
```

Not too bad!

About memory usage, I guess if `reshape` handles it my solution will, if you can work with my assumptions or preprocess the data to meet them:

- data is sorted
- we have 3 columns only
- for all id values we find all tms values

Comment: Thanks, I've tested your attempt three times under the same RAM exhausting conditions (8:8GB). It failed after around five minutes with the same `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`, though.

Comment: Anyway, `matrix_spread` seems to be quite fast for other purposes! :)