# Efficiently reshaping big datasets

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

The World Development Indicator looks as follows

```
library(data.table)
WDI <- fread("CountryName   CountryCode IndicatorName   IndicatorCode   1960    1961    2017
ArabWorld   ARB A   FX.OWN.TOTL.ZS  37.16521072 37.16521072 37.16521072
ArabWorld   ARB B   FX.OWN.TOTL.FE.ZS   25.63540268 25.63540268 25.63540268
ArabWorld   ARB C   FX.OWN.TOTL.MA.ZS   48.32851791 48.32851791 48.32851791
ArabWorld   ARB D   FX.OWN.TOTL.OL.ZS   42.54204559 42.54204559 42.54204559
ArabWorld   ARB E   FX.OWN.TOTL.40.ZS   27.72478104 27.72478104 27.72478104
ArabWorld   ARB F   FX.OWN.TOTL.PL.ZS   26.45811081 26.45811081 26.45811081
ArabWorld   ARB G   FX.OWN.TOTL.60.ZS   43.44695282 43.44695282 43.44695282
ArabWorld   ARB H   FX.OWN.TOTL.SO.ZS   48.66697693 48.66697693 48.66697693
ArabWorld   ARB I   FX.OWN.TOTL.YG.ZS   20.95479965 20.95479965 20.95479965
", header = TRUE)
```

I used the following code to reshape the World Development Indicator Database from the World Bank.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

WDI <- WDI %>% 
  select(-`Indicator Name`) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`1960`:`2017`) %>% 
  spread(`Indicator Code`, val)
```

It used to work without any issues, but for some reason it now requires too much memory for the operation to be completed.

I have tried to remove all other databases from the work space, `gc()`, closing all other programs on the computer and to reduce the years used to reshape, but that did not fix the problem. As a result, I wonder whether there is a less memory intensive way to deal with the issue.

---

EDIT 1: According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077668/what-methods-can-we-use-to-reshape-very-large-data-sets) `dcast.data.table` or `reshape` (because of not running out of memory) is the way to go. I am however having a lot of trouble rewriting the syntax (I got the dplyr answer my posting a question as well) How would I rewrite the `dplyr` code for using dcast/reshape?

How do the terms `select`, `gather`, `spread`, relates to dcast and reshape?

---

EDIT 2: I have first tried to melt the data.table as follows:

```
WDI = melt(WDI, id.vars = c("IndicatorCode", "CountryName", "CountryCode"),
               #  measure.vars = -c("IndicatorCode", "CountryName", "CountryCode", "IndicatorName"))
                measure.vars = c("1960", "1961","2017"))
colnames(WDI)[4] <- "year"
WDI = dcast(WDI, CountryName + CountryCode + year ~ IndicatorCode, value.var="value")
```

But then I get the "warning" `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length` and all entries are just 1 instead of the values. This apparently happens when the combination of entries are not unique. I am however pretty sure that they are (the combination of the country and the Indicator, should make the entry unique).

Comment: Seems relevant: [What methods can we use to reshape VERY large data sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077668/what-methods-can-we-use-to-reshape-very-large-data-sets)

Comment: I have put it in the post.

Comment: please help to clarify what is the gap in your understanding between the referenced post and applying it to your data set

Comment: I simply don't understand the how to move from the dplyr syntax to the dcast/reshape.. Or adapting the example post given. I'm having trouble exactly explaining why.. I just don't see it..

Comment: I can't read your data into 7 columns. Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Not sure what happened, should work now.

Comment: It still reads as two columns, see `dim(WDI)`. You have spaces in the values which confuses `fread`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I have removed all spaces now.

Comment: Try something like `dcast(melt(WDI, id = c(1:2, 4), measure = patterns("\\d+")), ... ~ IndicatorCode)` . Or you can pipe it if it easier to read: `melt(WDI, id = c(1:2, 4), measure = patterns("\\d+")) %>% dcast(., ... ~ IndicatorCode)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Wow, so that worked quick snap. Thank you so much. No hurry, but I would be really interested in the explanation behind this..

Comment: The `melt` part is exactly like you did, I just used two shortcuts: First, I've used columns locations instead of their names. Second- I've used the `patterns` (see `?patterns`) function in order to get all the columns I want to measure at once (`\\d+` is just a lazy regex for taking the columns with numeric titles). In `dcast` I also did something very similar to your attempt but with yet another shortcut- `...` just means "take all the columns". data.table figures by itself that it needs to use `value` as the column for aggregation. You don't really need all these shortcuts- I'm just lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WDI dataset is not particularly large, so I suspect that your `gather` command is excluding columns that are unique per row, causing an enormous amount of duplication, e.g. an extra year column like `2018`.

You could be more explicit with your `select` command to avoid that by positively selecting only the columns you need rather than negatively excluding specific columns, like so...

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

url <- "http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDI_csv.zip"
zippath <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file(url, zippath)

csvpath <- unzip(zippath, files = "WDIData.csv", exdir = tempdir())

WDI <- readr::read_csv(csvpath)

WDI %>% 
  select(`Country Name`, `Country Code`, `Indicator Code`, `1960`:`2017`) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`1960`:`2017`) %>% 
  spread(`Indicator Code`, val)
```

or you could make sure that columns that you do not need in the reshape are excluded, like so...

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

url <- "http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDI_csv.zip"
zippath <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file(url, zippath)

csvpath <- unzip(zippath, files = "WDIData.csv", exdir = tempdir())

WDI <- readr::read_csv(csvpath)

WDI %>% 
  select(-`Indicator Name`, -`2018`, -`X64`) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`1960`:`2017`) %>% 
  spread(`Indicator Code`, val)
```

you can also avoid some intermediate size inflation by using `gather`'s `na.rm = TRUE` option, which might speed things up a bit...

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

url <- "http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDI_csv.zip"
zippath <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file(url, zippath)

csvpath <- unzip(zippath, files = "WDIData.csv", exdir = tempdir())

WDI <- readr::read_csv(csvpath)

WDI %>% 
  select(-`Indicator Name`, -`2018`, -`X64`) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`1960`:`2017`, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(`Indicator Code`, val)
```

---

and for a bit more explanation, notice what happens if you "accidentally" don't include 2017 in your gather command using the example dataset you created above...

```r
library(data.table)
WDI <- fread("CountryName   CountryCode IndicatorName   IndicatorCode   1960    1961    2017
ArabWorld   ARB A   FX.OWN.TOTL.ZS  37.16521072 37.16521072 37.16521072
ArabWorld   ARB B   FX.OWN.TOTL.FE.ZS   25.63540268 25.63540268 25.63540268
ArabWorld   ARB C   FX.OWN.TOTL.MA.ZS   48.32851791 48.32851791 48.32851791
ArabWorld   ARB D   FX.OWN.TOTL.OL.ZS   42.54204559 42.54204559 42.54204559
ArabWorld   ARB E   FX.OWN.TOTL.40.ZS   27.72478104 27.72478104 27.72478104
ArabWorld   ARB F   FX.OWN.TOTL.PL.ZS   26.45811081 26.45811081 26.45811081
ArabWorld   ARB G   FX.OWN.TOTL.60.ZS   43.44695282 43.44695282 43.44695282
ArabWorld   ARB H   FX.OWN.TOTL.SO.ZS   48.66697693 48.66697693 48.66697693
ArabWorld   ARB I   FX.OWN.TOTL.YG.ZS   20.95479965 20.95479965 20.95479965
", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

WDI %>% 
  select(-`IndicatorName`) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`1960`:`1961`) %>% 
  spread(`IndicatorCode`, val)
```

Comment: Very nice! Also the addition of showing how to automatically download the file.