# Transforming a dataframe in r to apply pivot table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like below:

```
       Red  Green   Black
John    A   B       C
Sean    A   D       C
Tim     B   C       C
```

How can I transform it to below form to apply a pivot table (or if it can be done directly in r without transforming data):

```
Names   Code    Type
John    Red     A
John    Green   B
John    Black   C
Sean    Red     A
Sean    Green   D
Sean    Black   C
Tim     Red     B
Tim     Green   C
Tim     Black   C
```

So then my ultimate goal is to count the types as below by a pivot table on the transformed dataframe:

````
Count of Code for each type:

Row Labels  A   B   C   D   Grand Total
John            1   1   1       3      
Sean            1       1   1   3
Tim             1   2           3
Grand Total  2  2   4   1       9
```
reading similar topics did not help that much. 

Thanks in advance!
Regards
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a literal dump from your first matrix-like frame above:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Red = c("A", "A", "B"), Green = c("B", "D", "C"
), Black = c("C", "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("John", 
"Sean", "Tim"))
```

I can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble::rownames_to_column(dat, var = "Names") %>%
  gather(Code, Type, -Names)
#   Names  Code Type
# 1  John   Red    A
# 2  Sean   Red    A
# 3   Tim   Red    B
# 4  John Green    B
# 5  Sean Green    D
# 6   Tim Green    C
# 7  John Black    C
# 8  Sean Black    C
# 9   Tim Black    C
```

We can extend that to get your next goal:

```r
tibble::rownames_to_column(dat, var = "Names") %>%
  gather(Code, Type, -Names) %>%
  xtabs(~ Names + Type, data = .)
#       Type
# Names  A B C D
#   John 1 1 1 0
#   Sean 1 0 1 1
#   Tim  0 1 2 0
```

which then just needs marginals:

```r
tibble::rownames_to_column(dat, var = "Names") %>%
  gather(Code, Type, -Names) %>%
  xtabs(~ Names + Type, data = .) %>%
  addmargins()
#       Type
# Names  A B C D Sum
#   John 1 1 1 0   3
#   Sean 1 0 1 1   3
#   Tim  0 1 2 0   3
#   Sum  2 2 4 1   9
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I face with error as could not find function "rownames_to_column", while I have loaded both libraries.

Comment: My apologies, I thought that `dplyr` was re-exporting that. I'll fix it. (`tibble`)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reshape()`. I'm not sure about your data structure, if there is a column with names or if they are row names. I've added both versions.

```
reshape(dat1, idvar="Names",
        varying=2:4,
        v.names="Type", direction="long",
        timevar="Code", times=c("red", "green", "black"),
        new.row.names=1:9)

reshape(transform(dat2, Names=rownames(dat2)), idvar="Names",
        varying=1:3,
        v.names="Type", direction="long",
        timevar="Code", times=c("red", "green", "black"),
        new.row.names=1:9)

#     V1  Code Type
# 1 John   red    A
# 2 Sean   red    A
# 3  Tim   red    B
# 4 John black    B
# 5 Sean black    D
# 6  Tim black    C
# 7 John green    C
# 8 Sean green    C
# 9  Tim green    C
```

To get kind of a raw version you could do:

```
res <- reshape(transform(dat2, Names=rownames(dat2)), idvar="Names",
               varying=1:3,
               v.names="Type", direction="long",
               timevar="Code")
res
#        Names Code Type
# John.1  John    1    A
# Sean.1  Sean    1    A
# Tim.1    Tim    1    B
# John.2  John    2    B
# Sean.2  Sean    2    D
# Tim.2    Tim    2    C
# John.3  John    3    C
# Sean.3  Sean    3    C
# Tim.3    Tim    3    C
```

After that you may assign labels at will to `"Code"` column by transforming to `factor` like so:

```
res$Code <- factor(res$Code, labels=c("red", "green", "black"))
```

### Data

```
dat1 <- structure(list(Names = c("John", "Sean", "Tim"), Red = c("A", 
"A", "B"), Green = c("B", "D", "C"), Black = c("C", "C", "C")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

dat2 <- structure(list(Red = c("A", "A", "B"), Green = c("B", "D", "C"
), Black = c("C", "C", "C")), row.names = c("John", "Sean", "Tim"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Nice use of base R. I have to re-read the docs for `reshape` every time I want to use it, much of it seems so not-obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was an simple example. My df has 600 names, and 800 codes and 7 types. not sure how to amend the code so that it can be run.

Comment: @Sean See update with a "raw" version. It creates the "code" column as numeric. You could either assign labels later as shown in my example or include it into the `reshape` call as in the previous versions.

Comment: @r2evans Thx! I know, I know :) but I think it's worth it (at least since my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55077668/6574038)). It has some really nice features, some of them I've never used like `split` option.

Answer (score 0):

What you aim to do is (1) creating a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) and then (2) compute the sum of table entries for both rows and columns.

### Step1: Create a contingency table

I first pivoted the data using `pivot_longer()` rather than `gather()` because it's more intuitive. Then, apply `table()` to the two variables of your interest.

```
# Toy example 

df <- structure(list(Red = c("A", "A", "B"), Green = c("B", "D", "C"
), Black = c("C", "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("John", 
"Sean", "Tim"))

# Pivot the data 
long_df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(df, var = "Names") %>%
  tidyverse::pivot_longer(cols = c(-Names),
               names_to = "Type", 
               values_to = "Code") 

# Create a contingency table 
df_table <- table(long_df$Names, long_df$Code)
```

### Step 2: Compute the sum of entries for both rows and columns.

Again, I only used a base R function `margin.table()`. Using this approach also allows you to save the sum of the row and column entries for further analysis.

```
# Grand total (margin = 1 indicates rows)
df_table %>%
  margin.table(margin = 1)

# Grand total (margin = 2 indicates columns)
df_table %>%
  margin.table(margin = 2)
```