# more efficient alternative for reshape?

Tags: r

I try to pivot data in a dataframe, below code works for small dataframe, however for a bigger one (80k rows) it's just running seamingly forever.

`reshape(SumData,direction = "wide",idvar = c("location","lat","lon","year"), timevar = "variable")`

("variable" column has just two values if that matters)

Is there a more efficient way for this?

Comment: It depends if you want to stick with `base` R or move to `tidyr` (see [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/)) and `data.table` (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) for reshaping data). Out of the 2 options, `data.table` should have much higher performance.

Comment: Efficient package methods might also have their limits, consider my question on [what-methods-can-we-use-to-reshape-very-large-data-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55077668/6574038)