# How to convert nested for-loops to lapply for code optimization in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, purrr

I am trying to convert the for loop into any apply family for code optimization

Here is the sample data

```
my_data = structure(list(Sector = c("AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "CCC", "AAA",
    "BBB", "AAA", "CCC"), Sub_Sector = c("AAA1", "BBB1", "AAA1",
    "CCC1", "AAA1", "BBB2", "AAA1", "CCC2"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), type = c("Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual",
    "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
    -8L))
```

Actual Function (Using for loop) this function gives us the expected output

```
expand_collapse_compliance <- function(right_table){
  
  sector_list <- unique(right_table$Sector)
  df = data.frame("Sector1"=c(""),"Sector"=c(""),"Sub_Sector"=c(""),"Actual"=c(""))
  
  for(s in sector_list){
    df1 = right_table[right_table$Sector==s,]
    sector1 = df1$Sector[1]
    Sector = df1$Sector[1]
    Sub_Sector = ""
    actual = as.character(nrow(df1))
    mainrow = c(sector1,Sector,Sub_Sector,actual)
    df = rbind(df,mainrow)
    Sub_Sector_list <- unique(df1$Sub_Sector)
    
    for(i in Sub_Sector_list){
      df2 = right_table[right_table$Sub_Sector==i,]
      sector1 = df1$Sector[1]
      Sector = ""
      Sub_Sector = df2$Sub_Sector[1]
      actual = nrow(df2)
      subrow = c(sector1,Sector,Sub_Sector,actual)
      df = rbind(df,subrow)
    }
  }
  df = df[2:nrow(df),]
  df$Actual = as.numeric(df$Actual)
  df_total = nrow(right_table)
  df = rbind(df,c("","Total","",df_total))
  return(df)
  
}

DT::datatable(expand_collapse_compliance(mydata1), 
              rownames = F,escape = FALSE,
              selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),
              options = list(pageLength = 50,scrollX = TRUE,
                             dom = 'tp',ordering=F,
                             columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=0),
              list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))),class='hover cell-border stripe')
```

i tried to convert inner loop to lapply first while doing that the sub_sector value is not showing in the output table, please let me know how to fix any idea would be appreciated

```
expand_collapse_compliance <- function(right_table){
  sector_list <- unique(right_table$Sector)
  df = data.frame("Sector1"=c(""),"Sector"=c(""),"Sub_Sector"=c(""),"Actual"=c(""))
  
  for(s in sector_list){
    df1 = right_table[right_table$Sector==s,]
    sector1 = df1$Sector[1]
    Sector = df1$Sector[1]
    Sub_Sector = ""
    actual = as.character(nrow(df1))
    mainrow = c(sector1,Sector,Sub_Sector,actual)
    df = rbind(df,mainrow)
    Sub_Sector_list <- unique(df1$Sub_Sector)
    
    #for(i in Sub_Sector_list){
      lapply(Sub_Sector_list, function(x){
      df2 = right_table[right_table$Sub_Sector==Sub_Sector_list,]
      sector1 = df1$Sector[1]
      Sector = ""
      Sub_Sector = df2$Sub_Sector[1]
      actual = nrow(df2)
      subrow = c(sector1,Sector,Sub_Sector,actual)
      df = rbind(df,subrow)
      })
  }
  df = df[2:nrow(df),]
  df$Actual = as.numeric(df$Actual)
  df_total = nrow(right_table)
  df = rbind(df,c("","Total","",df_total))
  return(df)
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you could do:

Note: I dropped the `DT` part.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expand_collapse_compliance1 <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>% 
    count(Sector, Sub_Sector, name = "Actual") %>% 
    group_split(Sector) %>% 
    lapply(function(x) {
      main <- group_by(x, Sector) %>% summarise(Actual = sum(Actual)) 
      bind_rows(main, x)
    }) %>%
    bind_rows() %>% 
    mutate(Sector1 = Sector) %>%
    select(Sector1, Sector, Sub_Sector, Actual)
  
  total <- x %>%
    filter(is.na(Sub_Sector)) %>% 
    group_by(Sector = "Total") %>% 
    summarise(Actual = sum(Actual))
  
  bind_rows(x, total) %>% 
    mutate(Sector = ifelse(!is.na(Sub_Sector), "", Sector)) %>% 
    replace_na(list(Sub_Sector = "", Sector1 = ""))
}

expand_collapse_compliance1(my_data)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   Sector1 Sector  Sub_Sector Actual
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>       <int>
#> 1 "AAA"   "AAA"   ""              4
#> 2 "AAA"   ""      "AAA1"          4
#> 3 "BBB"   "BBB"   ""              2
#> 4 "BBB"   ""      "BBB1"          1
#> 5 "BBB"   ""      "BBB2"          1
#> 6 "CCC"   "CCC"   ""              2
#> 7 "CCC"   ""      "CCC1"          1
#> 8 "CCC"   ""      "CCC2"          1
#> 9 ""      "Total" ""              8

expand_collapse_compliance(my_data)
#>    Sector1 Sector Sub_Sector Actual
#> 2      AAA    AAA                 4
#> 3      AAA              AAA1      4
#> 4      BBB    BBB                 2
#> 5      BBB              BBB1      1
#> 6      BBB              BBB2      1
#> 7      CCC    CCC                 2
#> 8      CCC              CCC1      1
#> 9      CCC              CCC2      1
#> 91          Total                 8
```

Comment: Thanks you so much stefan

Comment: I checked your code in the [benchmark in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70461290/6574038), probably something in it is not working properly yet? Or I have a flaw in my new sample data.

Comment: Hej @jay.sf. Yep. In my tidy approach the `Sub_Sector`s are ordered alphabetically, i.e. with your example data it results in `A1`, `A10`, ... instead of `A1`, `A2`, ... Moreover, in my tidy approach `Actual` is a numeric while running your function it is character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473732/for-loop-conversation-to-apply-variants-in-r-for-code-optimization         <- i have a similar question with multiple columns kindly check and let me know your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate function of the `*apply` family could be `tapply` using a split-apply-combine approach. Since we need `tapply` only when there are multiple `Sub_Sector`'s, we implement a case handling for sake of speed.

```
expand_collapse_complianceA <- \(data) {
  r <- do.call(rbind, c(by(data, data$Sector, \(x) {
    if (length(unique(x$Sub_Sector)) != 1L) {
      tt <- t(unname(with(x, tapply(count, list(Sector, Sub_Sector), sum))))
      tt <- cbind(x[!duplicated(x$Sub_Sector), 1:2], foo='', Actual=tt)
    } else {
      tt <- as.data.frame(t(c(unlist(x[!duplicated(x$Sub_Sector), 1:2]), foo='',
                              Actual=sum(x$count))))
    }
    rbind(c(tt[1, 1], '', tt[1, 1], sum(as.numeric(tt[, 4]))), tt)[c(1, 3, 2, 4)]
  }), make.row.names=FALSE))
  rbind(r, c('', 'Total', '', sum(as.numeric(r$Actual[!r$foo %in% ''])))) |>
    setNames(c('Sector1', 'Sector', 'Sub_Sector', 'Actual'))
}
```

**Note:** `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)`.

### Gives

```
expand_collapse_compliance(my_data)
#   Sector1 Sector Sub_Sector Actual
# 1     AAA    AAA                 4
# 2     AAA              AAA1      4
# 3     BBB    BBB                 2
# 4     BBB              BBB1      1
# 5     BBB              BBB2      1
# 6     CCC    CCC                 2
# 7     CCC              CCC1      1
# 8     CCC              CCC2      1
# 9          Total                 8


expand_collapse_complianceA(my_data) |> 
  (\(x) DT::datatable(
    x, rownames=F, escape=FALSE, selection=list(mode="single", target="row"), 
    options=list(pageLength=50, scrollX=TRUE, dom='tp', ordering=F, 
                 columnDefs=list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=0),
                                 list(className='dt-left', targets='_all'))), 
    class='hover cell-border stripe'))()
```

[image]

`expand_collapse_complianceA` now needs just 1/10 of the time as the original `for` loop. Here a **benchmark** (tested on 1080 rows).

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
#    ecc_for 304.723781 305.426934 346.878188 308.208294 335.944407 598.94351    10   c
# ecc_tapply  29.768177  29.851975  31.083977  30.611982  32.058980  34.50901    10 a  
#   ecc_tidy 135.326594 135.952068 143.967550 138.475437 149.352409 164.94652    10  b 
#     ecc_DT   3.267969   3.611711   4.610916   3.664493   3.707528  13.48797    10 a
```

Of course data.table is faster. However, I's like to see performance when the data is about to [exhaust the RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077668/what-methods-can-we-use-to-reshape-very-large-data-sets).

*Benchmark Code:*

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ecc_for=expand_collapse_compliance(dat),
  ecc_tapply=expand_collapse_complianceA(dat),
  ecc_tidy={library(dplyr);library(tidyr);expand_collapse_compliance1(dat)},
  ecc_DT={library(data.table);expand_collapse_complianceDT(as.data.table(dat))},
  times=10L)
```

**Note,** that the "tidy" version has some flaws so far (at least with the new data).

```
res_for <- expand_collapse_compliance(dat)
res_tapply <- expand_collapse_complianceA(dat)
res_tidy <- {library(dplyr);library(tidyr);expand_collapse_compliance1(dat)}


all.equal(res_for, res_tapply, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(res_for, res_tidy, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] "Component “Sub_Sector”: 1053 string mismatches"             
# [2] "Component “Actual”: target is character, current is numeric"
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- expand.grid(Sector=c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", 
                     "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", 
                     "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BA"),
            Sub_Sector=1:40, stringsAsFactors=F)
dat <- transform(dat, Sub_Sector=Reduce(paste0, dat[1:2]), count=1, type='Actual')
dat <- dat[order(dat$Sector), ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jay.sf

Comment: @Eliyas You're welcome, note the update with enhanced version of your `for` loop.

Comment: Be carefull though on such speedtests on very tiny sample data. Often `for` loops look faster as any other library's function calls take a tiny tiny bit of extra time ONCE but that you win back HUGE time processing some actual data.

Comment: can you tell how to check the differences @Jay.sf

Comment: Let me post some test below my answer.

Comment: i think you forget to define sector_list in the code

Comment: df <- type.convert(as.data.frame(M), as.is=TRUE) |>
    setNames(c('Sector1', 'Sector', 'Sub_Sector', 'count')) i am getting an error in the line

Comment: @Eliyas Thanks, `sector_list` replaced. You probably have an old R version, you need R > 4.1 for the `|> ` pipe.

Comment: @Eliyas Actually I think your original function performs well, what is the reason you want to change it?

Comment: can you tell me how to check the time differences @jay.sf

Comment: @Eliyas Yes, see update. We don't have appropriate data yet, though.

Comment: @Eliyas Please note, I've corrected a flaw in `expand_collapse_complianceA()`, it also added the Actual of Sector to the Total.

Comment: sure and thanks for everything @jay.sf

Comment: @Eliyas Forget the new for loop, actually your idea with the `*apply` family was great and `tapply` actually is fastest, see updated benchmark.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg Thanks for the objection, you were really right! I created some better testing data and rerun the benchmark!

Comment: @jay.sf it is usually not fair either to include your library calls **within** your benchmark

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg I have the different opinion, that everything necessary should be included (apart from R), at least to see both versions. It's similar when parallelizing code, the time to start the clusters, or in `for` loops to define objects before the loop; actually _not_ including all this could also be seen as cheating.

Comment: Works two ways, usually people have either tidiverse or data.table as their way to go. You just have them loaded anyhow. Sure sometimes you prefer base for certain tasks. I always use data.table by personal preference and it loads in .Rprofile. No need to punish every single piece of code by the libraries. So if you benchmark 2 functions using one library? Do you then share the load?

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg I haven't loaded any of both, though, just clutters my auto completion :)

Comment: "Of course data.table is faster. However, I's like to see performance when the data is about to exhaust the RAM." You probably gonna love data.table then even more as it tends to be way more memory efficient than others.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg I just put a link under it, did you notice?

Comment: Yes have seen it, but we are not dcasting here ;) It is always good to know the strength and weakness of any library and its functions. Anyhow this gets a bit too much off topic though.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg You made a point, maybe you should write a new article ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473732/for-loop-conversation-to-apply-variants-in-r-for-code-optimization <- i have a similar question with multiple columns kindly check and let me know your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any loops nor apply, what we want here is three different group counts and some formatting. With the assumption - and as seen in the sample data - there is no need for a split.

```
my_data = structure(list(Sector = c("AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "CCC", "AAA",
    "BBB", "AAA", "CCC"), Sub_Sector = c("AAA1", "BBB1", "AAA1",
    "CCC1", "AAA1", "BBB2", "AAA1", "CCC2"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), type = c("Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual",
    "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
    -8L))

library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)

expand_collapse_compliance <- function(x) {
  x <- rbindlist(list(
    x[, .(Sector1 = Sector, Actual = .N), by = Sector], 
    setnames(x[, .(Actual = .N), by = .(Sector, Sub_Sector)], "Sector", "Sector1"),
    x[, .(Sector = "Total", Actual = .N)]
  ), fill = T)
  setcolorder(x, c("Sector1", "Sector", "Sub_Sector", "Actual"))
  setorder(x, Sector1, Sector, na.last = T)
  x
}

expand_collapse_compliance(my_data)

#    Sector1 Sector Sub_Sector Actual
# 1:     AAA    AAA       <NA>      4
# 2:     AAA   <NA>       AAA1      4
# 3:     BBB    BBB       <NA>      2
# 4:     BBB   <NA>       BBB1      1
# 5:     BBB   <NA>       BBB2      1
# 6:     CCC    CCC       <NA>      2
# 7:     CCC   <NA>       CCC1      1
# 8:     CCC   <NA>       CCC2      1
# 9:    <NA>  Total       <NA>      8
```

**sidenote**
There is no need to convert `NA` to `""` as in shiny DT will show blancs for it.

**Speedtest**

As I mentioned that `for` is often faster on very small data sets as any library solutions use some functions that take some time to load once...

```
my_data_small = structure(list(Sector = c("AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "CCC", "AAA",
    "BBB", "AAA", "CCC"), Sub_Sector = c("AAA1", "BBB1", "AAA1",
    "CCC1", "AAA1", "BBB2", "AAA1", "CCC2"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), type = c("Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual",
    "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
    -8L))

library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)

   test replications elapsed relative
2  eccB          150    0.32     1.00
1 eccDT          150    0.72     2.25

# well just make it a milion times bigger :D
my_data_large <- rbindlist(rep(list(my_data_small), 1000000L))

   test replications elapsed relative
2  eccB           50   79.30    5.146
1 eccDT           50   15.41    1.000
```

Comment: Throws me ```Error in ```[.data.frame```(x, , .(Sector1 = Sector, Actual = .N), by = Sector) : 
unused argument (by = Sector)```

Comment: That error is caused because you did not used this part `library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)`

Comment: Ahh, of course! I've included your data.table version in my benchmark as well now! Can't the NA's transformed into `''`? OP seems to need it for their fancy table.

Comment: shiny DT shows blancs for true NA values as input, there is no need to make it an empty string.

Comment: Okay, confirmed!